# Erdas Imagine DN to TOA reflectance for SPOT images

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, spot5

I would like to convet DN to TOA reflectance in Erdas Imagine 2013. I see there is a way of doing this for Landsat7 in the Radiometric tab. How can I do this for SPOT2,4,5 images?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is indeed no pre-implemented module for the automated conversion of SPOT DN values to reflectance. If you insist on doing it in ERDAS Imagine, then you should use the Spatial Modeler for the conversion. Maybe [this](http://www.csun.edu/climate/Fire_Mapping_ASTER_PtII_L3_L4_with_title.pdf) might help you getting started.

You need to look up the gain parameters of the SPOT sensors in order to apply the right formulas in Spatial Modeler.